# Should/how can I avoid downcasting in this case?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, downcast

Say I have a base and derived class, where the derived class implements some additional manufacture specific functionality:

```
class Device {
// Base class
}

class DeviceFromSpecificManufacture : public Device {
// Derived
}
```

When my program runs, it requires the user to select a device from an array of available devices. At this point, it's fine for me to use the base class as I only require basic device functionality (nothing specific to the manufacture):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Device>> availableDevices = getAvailableDevices();

// User selects device here, resulting in:
std::shared_ptr<Device> selectedDevice = ...
```

The problem is: at some point I'm going to need to only work with the classes that implement manufacture specific functionality.

One way I can do this is by downcasting my base instance to the derived type, when the program is at a point where it needs to use the specific functionality.

```
std::shared_ptr<DeviceFromSpecificManufacture> specificDevice = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DeviceFromSpecificManufacture>(selectedDevice);

// Here I would need to confirm that the cast was successful (as there's no guarantee 
// that selectedDevice is an instance of DeviceFromSpecificManufacture) - which 
// makes this feel even more wrong.
```

Is there a better way to do this? I cannot move the specific functionality to the base class, as it's really not applicable to all devices, just some.

Comment: *"One way to do this.."* - that's the *only* way to do it without changing your storage mechanics or having your devices provide an `isA()` exposure of some sort. Even in those cases, all it would do is limit *where* you invoke that dynamic cast. Sooner or later it has to be done if you want a path back to the functionality provided exclusively by `DeviceFromSpecificManufacture`.

Comment: _"it's really not applicable to all devices, just some"_   
Isn't that what `virtual` is for ?

Comment: Do you only need device-specific _functionality_, with the same base interface? Or are there cases where more specific devices have a different _interface_, and you need to test for that? The best answer might differ based on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A downcast is almost always a symptom of a contradiction in the design. Your contradiction lies here:

> […] it's fine for me to use the base class as I only require basic device functionality […]
>
> […] I'm going to need to only work with the classes that implement manufacture specific functionality.

Apparently it's not fine for you to only know about the base class because, suddenly, it 
turns out you *do* have to know about the more concrete type!?

By having a piece of code take a `Device`, you express: This piece of code works with any kind of `Device`. If this piece of code has to then downcast the `Device` it was given and check whether it is of the kind of `Device` it actually can deal with, then we have to ask ourselves the question: If this piece of code cannot actually work with any kind of `Device`, why did it accept any kind of `Device` as input? What happens if this code is given a `Device` it can't work with? A component that has to downcast in its implementation says one thing and does another… recommended reading: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The problem is that what kind of design would work in your particular application depends on the particular application. Without knowing more about that application, it's very hard to suggest what would be a good way to fix the design. However, here are a few thoughts:

Why store all devices in the same collection? Why not store the devices in separate collections, one for each kind? That enables you to not just display the devices to the user, but display them by category. It also means you do not throw away the information you need.

Alternatively, even if you do not know the concrete types of all objects in your data structure, the objects themselves always know what they are. The [Double Dispatch pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) (basically a version of the Visitor pattern) may be of interest to you.

Finally, whenever you see an `std::shared_ptr`, ask yourself: Does this object really have more than one owner? Actual shared ownership scenarios should be rather rare. In your case, you seem to be storing devices in a container. Chances are that whatever contains that container is the sole owner of these devices. Thus [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would probably be a more appropriate choice…

Answer (score 0):

Use the visitor pattern to call the device specific behaviour https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Generally the approach to this would be to make the base class have a default implementation of the function that does nothing at all. Then only override it in derived classes which need to do something. Such as:

```
class Device {
    virtual void PerformSpecialFunctionality {
        // Base implementation does nothing at all
    }
}

class DeviceA {
    // Does not override PerformSpecialFunctionality becuase it doesn't need to do anything special
}

class DeviceB : public Device {
    void PerformSpecialFunctionality override {
        // Does something specific to only DeviceB
    }
}
```

You can also supplement this with other methods that express other information that whether a derived class is different in some way. Such as:

```
virtual bool HasSpecialFunctionality {
    return false; // Only some derived classes override this to return true.
}
```

But that part could also be unnecessary overkill. It depends on what you really need.