# What is a good design pattern for getting object of specific derived class from a list of base class pointers?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Imagine I have a class called `Test` and inside this class I have a list of pointers which their types are all from class `Base`. Although any pointer which is stored in list is pointer to an object from classes which are derived from class `Base`. I want to provide a `getter()` function for a specific derived type which returns the object of specific class. Note that we don't know the index of required pointer inside class.

```
class Base
{
    /// Base class do have a pure virtual function
};

class Derived1
{
};

class Derived2
{
};


Class Test
{
    std::vector<Base*> pointers; /// any STL collection... vector may be more frequent

     get_derived1_object(); /// 
};
```

I think of some possible implementations of `get_derived1_object()` like this (And in my opinion both have some problems):

1- storing a copy pointer of `Derived1`'s object's pointer inside class. In case I want to try using `unique_pre` it is not a good solution.

2- iterate over `pointers` in order to find which item is from `Derived1` class using runtime type checking. (for example trying to use `dynamic_cast` or sth similar). In my usecase, using runtime type checking is better not to be used.

P.S: having multiple items of each class is not important here because I'm sure I don't have 2 different pointers from same class inside my list and consider it taken care of.

I was wondering if I could find the best solution for providing a function like `get_derived1_object` (whether from my own given solutions or sth else).

Comment: FYI: [Mapping Types to Values (in C++)](https://gpfault.net/posts/mapping-types-to-values.txt.html)

Comment: FYI: [SO: Use data type (class type) as key in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9859390/7478597)

Comment: Needing to know the type of a `Base*` would normally be considered a code smell. It would be easier to give a good answer if you could provide some more details on **why** you need this and **how** it will be used.

Comment: this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365859/should-how-can-i-avoid-downcasting-in-this-case

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a vector, use an associative map of `std::type_index` to base pointer. Ensure that only matching type index is used, and then you don't need dynamic_cast, because we know that the type will match the mapped pointer. That said, use of `std::type_index` still relies on RTTI. No linear searching is needed.